# Do I need to save my Mapbox token in a environment variable?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I just switched from gmaps to Mapbox, and I want to keep my account and tokens safe.

I have already added a set of urls that are able to reach my mapbox service
I have the default scopes:

styles: tiles
styles:read
fonts:read
dataset:read
vision:read

In my app, I just show some markers on the screen and show a pop up on hover, so i think those scopes are fine.

The thing is my token is on the client, so it i visible to the public.

Is this correct? or do i have to send it from the backend or something? buteven in that case it would still show in the client, is this ok?

Comment: You can also add url restrictions: https://docs.mapbox.com/help/how-mapbox-works/access-tokens/#using-url-restrictions

Comment: and rotate tokens: https://docs.mapbox.com/help/how-mapbox-works/access-tokens/#token-rotation

Comment: Thanks guys, i've done the url restrictions already, and rotate them, i dont need to as its a brand new key. So i guess i'm fine right?

Comment: I guess so. The url restrictions seems to be a new feature. It didn't exist a few months ago when I was checking their ways to secure tokens.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is correct: exposing the public API token (`pk.something`) in the JavaScript front end. The risk it sounds like you're attempting to mitigate against is the risk of someone grabbing your token to make their own API calls. Setting URL restrictions (as you have done) and occasionally rotating the tokens is the correct way to do that.